# REST call (HTTP) to RECURSIVELY get ALL files starting from (filtering by) a certain SharePoint Path

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I need to write the **HTTP query** (will call it from a Python script) to get ALL the files (including from all sub-folders of sub-folders) starting from a specific SharePoint Path. I need to run this on a SharePoint 2016 installation.

My Path is something like: `https://<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/<library-name>/folder1/sub-folder1`

I've been making a lot of attempts around this:

```
https://<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<library-name>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,File&$expand=File
```

I **could** obtain a long list of items (files and folders) with the needed info; below is am extract from such an item:

```
...
, {
    "odata.type": "SP.Data.EngineeringItem",
    "File": {
        "odata.type": "SP.File",
        "Name": "sample.pptx",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/<library-name>/some-other-folder-path/.../not-needed.pptx",
    },
    "FileLeafRef": "sample.pptx"
},

...
, {
    "odata.type": "SP.Data.EngineeringItem",
    "File": {
        "odata.type": "SP.File",
        "Name": "sample.pptx",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/<library-name>/folder1/sub-folder1/needed.docx",
    },
    "FileLeafRef": "sample.pptx"
},
```

***THE PROBLEM*** is that I cannot filter them more than this. I'm getting the content of the whole library, and I can't figure out how to filter based on the folder path (in my example, ***folder1/sub-folder1***)

How could I do that ?

I tried adding `&$filter=...` but I could not figure out how to refer to the `ServerRelativeUrl` field.

**Also**, where could I find a list of accepted values to use with`?$select=...` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more attempts, I was able to find a solution for this. I'm posting it here in case anybody else runs into anything similar and this helps...

1. `ServerRelativeUrl` is what's called a *hidden* field, so it cannot be used in the filter element.

*However*...

2. By Pasting the `https://<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<library-name>')/fields` URL in the browser (as it was suggested to me [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/295372/79664)), I was able to find the full list of fields available (turned out that the SP installation I have to work with has several customizations...), and I could spot one field called `FileRef` which worked ok to be used for filtering.

So the final URL that works with a **GET** operation is `https://<my-sharepoint-host>/<subsite>/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<library-name>')/items?$select=File,File/ServerRelativeUrl,FileRef&$expand=File&$filter=startswith(FileRef, '<subsite> + '/' + <library-name> + /folder1/sub-folder1')`