# In a REST call to '/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('title')/items?$select=... , what are the allowed fields?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, file

Where could I find a list with these allowed values ?

I could use, for example, `FileLeafRef`, `File`, `*`.

But I could not find these values documented somewhere.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a query without $select you will get all fields

Comment: That's not how it works for me. For example, if I run a query without "$select", the "FileLeafRef" is missing...

Comment: Please try _api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('title')/fields

Comment: that's not working, I get "{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147467261, System.ArgumentNullException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type"}}}"

Comment: I'm not sure why that is... You can construct that url and paste it in your browser to get the raw xml ouput.

Comment: this last advice actually helped. pasting the URL ending in '/fields' in my browser gave me a long XML, and then I was able to find the list of fields. Further on, this helped me fix my other, bigger, ROOT problem (what I posted here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/295346/rest-call-http-to-get-all-files-including-from-all-sub-folders-of-sub-folders ). So Thanks a lot !